# I need Iron powder. What's the best way to produce it?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metal

I have Ferric Chloride and Aluminum...

I also have steel filings from grinding steel objects, though some Iron Oxide have be separated (I do have Oxalic Acid and Citric Acid). Though that would give me steel powder, not iron.

Which is the most economical and would yield purest samples?

Comment: If you can figure this out, there are some steel makers who would like to talk to you. You can invite them to a conference at your private island.

Comment: I suggest buying iron powder. It's rather cheap, isn't it?

Comment: I think, that only way is sputtered iron melt. Or sand blasting using iron particles.  Using  wet chemistry, iron oxides will be produced  .

Answer (score 3):

Sigma-Aldrich has a [product](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/267953?lang=en&region=US) that is very pure but rather expensive. I suspect you can have high purity or low cost but not both.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a high grade metal file on some clean cast iron or an iron nail and coldest the metal shavings which is similar consistency to a powder. An iron nail would be galvanized though so you'd have to take the coating off first. Impurities may be present from the file though.

Comment: Those are unlikely to be near pure iron, which is very soft, more likely  to be high carbon steel.

Comment: The iron can be precipitated from the chloride salt by reacting it in solution with naoh and aqueous ammonia to form an iron ammonia complex then react that with glucose which should precipitate the metal .It won't be powder tho.